# How do I make audio continue to play when I switch to other consoles&users with Ctrl+Alt+Fn?

Tags: audio, polkit

Is it possible to tell polkit to allow some players or some users to continue to play their audio during another user session? Or is there another workaround that does not involve... see below?

I don't care what happens if they all play their audio at the same time. All the users are mine anyway. It's just my device.

Important: I want to use pulseaudio, not alsa, and I do not want to (fully) disable polkit.

Comment: Is your user in the `audio` group?

Comment: IIRC all processes not associated with the current VT are put to sleep (but I'd have to look this up). So your player process needs to be detached. Also, Pulseaudio is usually per session, so you have to switch to [system-wide Pulseaudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide/), which they [advise against](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/WhatIsWrongWithSystemWide/)

Comment: @muru Yes . . .